# Javascript working in Local (by Flywheel) but not in Live

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I have a site that runs perfectly on Local but on live (at Bluehost) it is as if my Javascript is not initialized at all. For example I have a scripts.js file with a console.log as first statement and the log entry does not show up in the console. None of my JS works on the pages:

```
    console.log('inside scripts.js');
    import "../css/style.css";
    import MobileMenu from "./modules/MobileMenu.js";
    import HeroSlider from "./modules/HeroSlider.js";
    import GoogleMap from "./modules/GoogleMap.js";
    import Search from "./modules/Search.js";
    import MyNotes from "./modules/MyNotes.js";
    import Like from "./modules/Like.js";
```

There are no errors in the console. I have checked all of my .js links manually in the browser and they are looking fine. What on earth am I doing wrong?

Website: https://fictional-varsity.site/

The Search button on my home page is supposed to open up an overlay and it does not even get that far (no errors displayed in the Console when I click on it).

Comment: It's because if you open you source code there is no reference to the scripts.js file at all

Comment: @Undry There is a `wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/bundled-assets/scripts.291f4fbd3120f33dcc5a.js`, it doesn't contain any `console.log`s though.

Comment: He is saying "I have a scripts.js file with a console.log as first statement", but he does not have a scripts.js file included

Comment: Guys, just want to clarify: my /js/scripts.js does not get 'processed' at all. I can put any junk in there and it does not even give me an error. 

I tried including /js/scripts.js with wp_enqueue_scripts in functions.php but then it gives me error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'. So how do I force WP to see and process /js/scripts.js?

By the way I'm using nodes.js & npm in Local so I'm not sure if I have do anything special in that regard in Live?